# Can't login when cookies are disabled in Chrome

Tags: support, login

With these settings in Chrome, everything works fine.

> [image]

But with these settings, I cannot login.

> [image]

And with the above settings, clicking these login buttons also do nothing, no effect, no response.

> [image]

Is this how Stack Exchange login is designed?

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: And not just Stack Exchange; many sites that allow you to interact at least need their own session cookies. As an aside, you'll also need (an exception in) the third party cookies, if you want to use the global auto-login. See "What else do I need" in [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: HAPL! I told my browser to not rememeber anything, and now it won't rememeber I've logged in!

Comment: That duplicate explains how to let chrome keep the settings you like but allow persistant and stack-exchage wide login using exceptions to the rule. It even has pictures! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, StackExchange stores a cookie with a session id on your computer. When you will disable cookies in browser settings, system will not response.